# An approach of shared libraries of plugins for Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, architecture, shared-libraries

Searching I noticed that generally in Zend Framework based applications, plugins are inside the library folder. But I'm trying to work in a way that different applications use the same library of plugins.

My intuition tells me that these plugins should be external to the application if another application can use it. What I am wanting to do is a library of plugins for my ZF applications. The structure I am looking for would be something like this:

```
www/
    zf-app-1/
    zf-app-2/

www-library/
    zf-my-plugins/
        database/
            EnttityManager.php
            DoctrineEntityManager.php
```

Thus, zf-app-1 and zf-app-2 use the same external plugin to them. I may be wrong, but this approach is more logical to me than zf-app-1 and zf-app-2 possesses a copy each of the same plugin folder in your library. Would you like opinions on this my thought.

But my question is about how to configure applications zf-app-1 and zf-app-2 to use this shared library. I would make it through the application.ini of each.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a shared library outside of your project folder like this:

*stuff/projects/zfproject1*
*stuff/projects/zf2project2*
*stuff/projects/zf2project3*
......
*stuff/shared/library* <--- shared libraries go in here

Let's assume a shared library called *MyLib*

*stuff/shared/library/MyLib*

You will need to

1. Add the library folder to your include path
2. Add the library namespace to the autoloader

Your application.ini:

```
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "MyLib_"
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../../../library"
```

Comment: This added to the include path. But how can I configure in `includePaths.library` multiple libraries? `includePaths.library` is not for the library application? I need this but need another, external and common to other applications. `zf-app-1` folder has it's own library folder but also must use an external. For example, I would like to `resources.entitymanager` (A plugin for Doctrine 2 for example) were external and common to many applications.

Comment: You should just be able to use `includePaths.library1 = "path/to/library1"` and then `includePaths.library2 = "path/to/library2"`. Even avoiding the keys altogether: `includePaths[] = "path/to/library1"` and `includePaths[] = "path/to/library2"`